# Override method with variable number of parameters

Tags: java

I have a method defined in an interface:

```
public Object g(String inter,String src,Object...params);
```

I am getting an error with the @Override annotation on the definition of the method in the implementing class:

```
public Object g(String inter,String src,Object...params) {}
```

Resolved: The issue was solved by cleaning the project and was probably caused by the Scala IDE

Comment: It should work fine, yet you have to add `return someObject`.

Comment: are you compiling for java6+?

Comment: @BalusC, Override for interfaces were not available in java5.

Comment: Don't use @Override for interfaces... you're not overriding anything, just implementing.

Comment: @Ryan: using Override is a good practice for methods implementing interface methods, for the same reason it's a good practice for methods overriding superclass methods: if the interface method disappears, you want to make sure the implementing class is modified.

Comment: Are you sure? My computer science teacher has always taught me not to use @Override for interfaces, and JBuilder 2007 won't let me. The problem could be that it's for a really old version of Java.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. It's usable for methods implementing an interface method since Java 6. JBuilder still exists?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said *which* error you're getting, but it should work fine other than you're currently not specifying a return value:

```
interface Foo {
    Object g(String inter, String src, Object...params);
}

class FooImpl implements Foo {
    @Override
    public Object g(String inter, String src, Object...params) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public interface testi {
    public Object g(String inter,String src,Object...params);
}

public class Test implements testi {
@Override
    public Object g(String inter,String src,Object...params) {
        Object o = new Object();
        return o;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you're using a Java 5 compiler. It's only since Java 6 that @Override can be used on methods overriding interface methods. In Java5, it was only allowed on methods overriding superclass methods.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet says, your code should be correct apart from the lack of return value. However, it is worth mentioning that java, prior to version 6, did not recognize the @Override annotation when implementing a method defined in an interface. On the off chance that you are using an older version, that might be causing your problem.